# Write info from list to Excel file using C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

In my C# code, I have a list with data that I want to write into an Excel file
using `Interop.Excel`.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 try
                {
                    xlsApp = new Excel.Application();
                    xlsWorkbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                    xlsWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlsWorkbook.Sheets[1];

                    // Create the header for Excel file
                    xlsWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "The Export Excels Function";
                    Excel.Range range = xlsWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "E1");
                    range.Merge(1);
                    range.Borders.Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                    range.Interior.Color = Color.Yellow.ToArgb();
                    #region get connection string from config file
                    int selectedIndex = DbCbx.SelectedIndex;
                    string[] listConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["listConnection"].Split(',');
                    connectionString = listConnection[selectedIndex];
                    #endregion
                    int i = 3;
                    if(IsOraDB.Checked)
                    {

                        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
                        OracleCommand cmdORA = new OracleCommand();
                        cmdORA.CommandText = sqlselect;
                        cmdORA.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        OracleDataReader dr = cmdORA.ExecuteReader();
                        #region set the max of progress
                        // Set Maximum to the total number of files to copy.
                        progress.Maximum = (int)dr.FieldCount;
                        #endregion
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < dr.FieldCount; ++j)
                            {
                                xlsWorksheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = dr.GetName(j);
                            }
                            ++i;
                        }

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            for (int j = 1; j <= dr.FieldCount; ++j)
                                xlsWorksheet.Cells[i, j] = dr.GetValue(j - 1);
                            ++i;
                            progress.PerformStep();
                        }
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                        conn.Open();
                        using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlselect, conn);
                        using SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        #region set the max of progress
                        // Set Maximum to the total number of files to copy.
                        progress.Maximum = (int)dr.FieldCount;
                        #endregion
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < dr.FieldCount; ++j)
                            {
                                xlsWorksheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = dr.GetName(j);
                            }
                            ++i;
                        }

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            for (int j = 1; j <= dr.FieldCount; ++j)
                                xlsWorksheet.Cells[i, j] = dr.GetValue(j - 1);
                            ++i;
                            progress.PerformStep();
                        }
                    }    
                   
                   

                    range = xlsWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "I" + (i + 2).ToString());
                    range.Columns.AutoFit();

                    xlsWorkbook.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
                        Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    xlsWorkbook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                    xlsApp.Quit();

                    ReleaseObject(xlsWorksheet);
                    ReleaseObject(xlsWorkbook);
                    ReleaseObject(xlsApp);

                    if (MessageBox.Show("Excel report has been created on your desktop\nWould you like to open it?", "Created Excel report",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        Process.Start(@"cmd.exe ", @"/c "+fileName);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error creating Excel report: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

add reference  and using

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

code for one sheat:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(missing);
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
        var oSheetItems = oSheet;
        if (oSheetItems != null)
        {
            oSheetItems.Name = "sheatName";
            int i = 1;

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                //insert your object
                oSheetItems.Cells[i, 1] = item;
                oSheetItems.Cells[i, 2] = item;
                i++;
            }
        }

        fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                   + "\\ExcelName.xlsx";
        oWB.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
            missing, missing, missing, missing,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        oWB.Close(missing, missing, missing);
        oXL.UserControl = true;
        oXL.Quit();
```

if need more sheat:
inter all code in loop an for every sheat use this code and
change sheat with:

```
 Excel.Worksheet oSheet2 = oWB.Sheets.Add(missing, missing, 1, missing);
                oSheetItems = oSheet2;
```